how to parallelize the following search in python?
I want to parallelized the following search of best parameters (I work on jupyter lab on macbook air(Apple M2 24Go))
def search(list):
    result=[0,0,0,0]
    for (a,b,c) in list:
         p= calcul(a,b,c)
         if p> result[0]:
             result=[p,a,b,c]
     return result

calcul is an auxiliary function which take positive values.
Thx in advance!

Do you compute in plain python, or using NumPy/PyTorch etc? With plain python you won't be able to speed up because of Global interpreter lock

At most you can try MPI, but it will be painful to implement, instead try to use NumPy/PyTorch properly, it will speed up automatically

@AlexeyS.Larionov https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/

You can use the multiprocessing module to calculate your intermediate values in parallel, and then find the maximum afterwards
import multiprocessing as mp

def mapper(args):
    a, b, c = args
    return [calcul(a, b, c), a, b, c]

def search(list):
    with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        mapped = pool.map(mapper, list)
        return max(mapped, key=lambda lst: lst[0])


I have replace  multiprocessing by multiprocess and it works. Thx!

you can use multiprocessing.Pool to run your calculations in parallel
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool

def calcul(Tuple):
    a,b,c = Tuple
    return a+b+c

def search():
    # demo data
    l = [(random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10),random.randint(0,10)) for _ in range(10)]
    print(l)
    
    with Pool() as pool: # parallel processing
        Result = pool.map(calcul,l)
    print(max(Result)) # maximum of the results

if __name__=="__main__": # run in this guard to not cause other issues
    search()

edit: i forgot to return the original parameters: see the answer by Caleth on this question
